# Prove $27\geq ab+bc+ca$

Tags: inequality

I happened upon the following [inequality on Arts of Problem Solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c509694h1967860_help_me_please) that I can not solve. I would very much like to see how to deal with this kind of problems.

Suppose real numbers $a,b,c >2$ and $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=a+b+c-8$. Prove $27\geq ab+bc+ca$.

Comment: Try multiplying both side of the equality given by $abc$. Then you'd have $$ab+bc+ca = a^2 bc +b^2 ca +c^2 ab -8.$$

Comment: It seems that you can find [something about this on AoPS](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Ba%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bb%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bc%7D%3Da%2Bb%2Bc-8%24%2C%20%2427%5Cgeq%20ab%2Bbc%2Bca%24&p=1).

Comment: Hey, moderators. I have edited the question to provide context. Please see if the question is fit for reopening.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Oh, thank you for the links and the math search website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $s=a+b+c$.
We have that $\frac{a-2}{a}+\frac{b-2}{b}+\frac{c-2}{c}=19-2s>0$, which implies that $s<\frac{19}{2}.\tag{*}$
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we get that $s-8=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\ge\frac{9}{s}\iff s\ge 9.\tag{**}$ 
Also by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we obtain that $$19-2s=\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{(a-2)^2}{a(a-2)}\ge \frac{(a+b+c-6)^2}{\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}a(a-2)}=\frac{(s-6)^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2-2s}=\frac{(s-6)^2}{s^2-2(ab+bc+ca)-2s}.$$
Thus, $$ab+bc+ca\le \frac{s^2}{2}-s-\frac{(s-6)^2}{2(19-2s)}$$ 
Since $\frac{s^2}{2}-s-\frac{(s-6)^2}{2(19-2s)}-27=\frac{(s-9)(s^2-2s-59)}{2s-19}\stackrel{(*)\text{ and }(**)}{\le}0$, we are done.